# WebRTC media server

Tags: c#, web-applications, server, uwp, webrtc

two days ago I started looking into WebRTC, looked at a view examples and tested it a bit myself, and it looks really interesting.

However my qustion is, what would be a good way of implementing a WebRTC "media server" in c#. The media server should be able to connect two clients, not peer to peer, but peer to server to peer. So I can for example record conversations on the server or have a group meeting.

Would it be possible to create a Windows service, which you can contact from a web application like ASP.Net?

I already had tons of tabs opened and found Microsofts WebRTC-UWP-SDK as well as their ORTC. Would they be able to work in a Windows service, or should I use the WebRTC native code? Maybe it is also possible to create a connection via a normal RTP connection?

All WebRTC media servers I found are either written in c, c++ or NodeJS.

So does anyone have an idea, what would be a good solution to implement a c# WebRTC media server, which can run on a windows server?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Did you end up finding a good solution for this?  I need to do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I know and have used one before. The media server is based on  .Net and has a lot of features and supports many programming languages and platforms. It is the Frozen Mountain's Liveswitch server.
See https://www.frozenmountain.com/products-services/liveswitch/ for more